# ¿Cómo subir un listado de imágenes a firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-storage

Estoy usando este código con la intención de subir un listado de imágenes  a firebase storage pero sólo se sube la primera foto. ¿Cuál es el error?

```
val refStorage = storage.reference.child("SpotFiles/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString())
spotVO.files?.forEach {
    refStorage.putFile(it.fileSpot!!).addOnSuccessListener {
        refStorage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri->
            list?.add(FileCaptureVO(uri,spotVO.nameSpot))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que subes todos los archivos a la misma ruta y por lo tanto se sobrescriben. La solución es darle un nombre diferente a cada archivo. Para lograrlo todo lo que debes hacer es poner la línea que genera el nombre del archivo dentro del forEach

```
spotVO.files?.forEach {
    val refStorage = storage.reference.child("SpotFiles/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    refStorage.putFile(it.fileSpot!!).addOnSuccessListener {
        refStorage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri->
            list?.add(FileCaptureVO(uri,spotVO.nameSpot))
        }
    }
}
```

Aunque si los archivos ya tienen un nombre único, podrías usar ese en vez de generar uno aleatorio.

Comment: si era eso lo pase por alto , muchas gracias